# how to make this kind of rope [ with bristles ]

Tags: modeling, particles, geometry-nodes, screw-modifier

i want to make this kind of rope.
any ideas how to do it , especially the bristles

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could create this kind of segment with half torus:

[image]

Then array it with an *Array* modifier:

[image]

As Chris says add some curve and give it a *Curve* modifier.
Paint a rope texture with the *Draw*, enable the *Texture* and *Mapping > Stencil*, give your object some hair.

Comment: and add some curve and give it a curve modifier.... ;)

Comment: sure I'm going to edit